# Xcode 4.3 stopped building XIB files

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a several XIB files in my iOS project for various custom table cells. I've just added another, but for some reason Xcode will not build this (or any subsequent) XIBs into the project !

The appropriate flags are set in the files inspector to include the XIB, and the XIB appears in the correct build phase. All XIBs were working as expected up until this point, and no settings have been altered in the project

[image: Project Settings]

I've experimented with adding more XIBs with different names, but none of them are getting built into the project (verified by inspecting the build application's NIB files).

[image: Look Mom, no NIB !]

What is going on ? Is this a bug in Xcode ? Anybody know how to resolve it ?

**Update**

I deleted the derived data directory, and lo and behold the NIB is now appearing in the build product - so I'll chalk this one up as a mysterious Xcode bug.

Comment: you could put that in as an answer - how to do it etc - damn only this morning I deleted derived data to get back autocomplete and definitions :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current version of Xcode, when things get weird and quitting+relaunching doesn't solve it, deleting your DerivedData folder usually will.

You can even do it as part of a build script or as a cron job:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is creating more classes and extra files AND it doesnt solve why this is happening but as a workaround you could try:

Creating a BlahCell class and set the nibs file's owner to it - if BlahCell.m is set to compile this may get your nib compiled.

I take it in other news a straight clean and build doesn't fix anything?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the derived data directory, and lo and behold the NIB is now appearing in the build product - so I'll chalk this one up as a mysterious Xcode bug.